# JScrollPane - how does it display JTable headers?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

What part of JScrollPane code is responsible for displaying the column headers of JTable?

If you just add a JTable to a JPanel, it won't show the headers by default. You should either pass the table to JScrollPane's constructor or call JScrollPane `setViewportView` with the table as the argument. So actually, what makes the column headers visible? Is it part of the internal rendering of the JScrollPane (`updateUI` and `getUI` methods)?

Initially I thought JScrollPane uses its `setColumnHeaderView` to accomplish this, but it doesn't (pass null to this method, the table will still display the headers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JTable` is responsible for doing this.

The `addNotify()` method of `JTable` is overridden. Basically this method is invoked when a component is added to a visible container.

So the `JTable` implementation checks if the parent of the table is a `JViewport`. If so it adds the table header to the scroll pane using the `setColumnHeaderView(...)` method.

Comment: Is there any explanation of why calling setColumnHeaderView doesn't update the column headers of the scroll pane? It's called after I've instantiated the scroll pane, added the JTable using setViewportView to it, and added the scroll pane to the JPanel. I've tried with repaint or revalidate on different components, no result. After I've created another table and extracted the table header from it, I passed it to setColumnHeaderView. No change. However, when I call setViewportView(null) after setColumnHeaderView, the scroll pane displays the headers of the second table.

Comment: @user4205580, You can change the column header of the scroll pane AFTER the frame is visible, not before. Because the table sets the column header when the frame is made visible as I explained above. If you have a problem, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.